# Spring Boot + Jetty servlet context path

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, jetty

I'm using Spring Boot with Jetty and when I'm getting path from `servletContext.getRealPath("/")` result look like that:

```
/private/var/folders/jg/94cgy2fs2mqckt3mx4fj52qm0000gn/T/jetty-docbase.7802968753762435172.8080/images/icons/bin.png
```

But should be like that or at least similar to:

```
User/myusername/projectname/web/resources
```

Also interesting fact if I have `webapp` folder some where jetty will use this folder like servlet context and `servletContext.getRealPath("/")` will return normal path.

Why Jetty works so strange  with servlet context and how I can get real path to the file in my file system?

Comment: how do you start your spring boot application?

Comment: @Funtik I have multi part project thats why i starting like that: gradle :web-admin:bootRun

Comment: looks like app has started in a temp folder. Try to pack it into executable jar and start with plain `java - jar`. Will the behaviour change?

Comment: I will try, but In current situation how I can get real path?

Comment: web containers are free to unpack and rearrange the location of resources to serve the webapp.  this is especially true of JSP, and `META-INF/resources/` based content.  what you are seeing is the combination of the jetty work directory and webapp specific temp directory being established by jetty.  (since you didn't declare either of them yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to get the absolute path of a current folder from inside of running JVM is:

```
new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thnx, that is works for me, also i found ClassPathResource can be used.

Comment: Note: that code should also produce the same results as `System.getProperty("user.dir")`